# How to use UIActivityIndicatorView in tableView after finish data fetching

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I tried to add an indicator before the tableview loads all the data, so I googled it and I found the following code and which worked perfect:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if let lastVisibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last {
    if indexPath == lastVisibleIndexPath {
        indicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

But the issue is that it only works when I have the data to load or have cell to display, when there is no data or no cell, the indicator will stay there and keep spinning. Can anyone tell me how to make a work around to solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Load model objects asynchronously and show activity indicator. In the completion block stop animating activity indicator. If you need example, plz share the code snippet of where you are loading the data model.

Comment: Can you show where you are calling your webservice to get the data?

Comment: how do you collect data for table? Can you show the codes?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to control the activity indicator view in the completionBlock of your API Call rather than doing it in will display cell Delegate method. See the example.

```
func makeAPICall() {
        indicator.startAnimating()
        YourAPIManger.yourAPICallWith(params) { (isAuthenticated, message) in
          indicator.stopAnimating()
          YourTableView.reload()

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply after getting all the data from your API, check if it is nil, then stopAnimating() your indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can add activity indicator on tableView footerView

```
lazy var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    activityIndicator.color = UIColor.gray
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    return activityIndicator
}()
```

and on tableView

```
func displayLoading() {
    tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
    spinner.startAnimating()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func hideLoading() {
    spinner.stopAnimating()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```